Fabric Icon Not Showing
I was using fabric icons using these cdn:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric-icons.min.css">
Now Icons are not showing up,
Button where I am using this icon
fabric.min.css
How do I fix this or is there any other alternative cdn?
The console shows this error for the fabric.icon.min.css
console image
and when I open the link for this file it shows this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric-icons.min.css">
fabric.icon.min.css link
I explored other CDN options but didn't find any suitable alternatives. Any advice on what I should do next?

Looks to me as if your CSP are interfering with the use of your CD?
Content Security Policy MDN docs
CSP blocking CDN, SO question
